# File Handling Permissions

Tags: python

So I am very new at file handling within python. I want to be able to read, write and append a text file all in one go. Here is what I think the code might look like:

```
name = input("Which file would you like to edit/view? \n --> ")
fhand = open((name), "r", "w", "a")
fhand.read()
fhand.write("Hello")
fhand.append("World")    
fhand.close()
```

However it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\godalming.ac.uk\dfs\UserAreas\Students\142659\test\filehandle tests.py", line 2, in <module>
fhand = open((name), "r", "w", "a")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Could you please advise on what is going wrong and how I could get around this?

Comment: Technical problems aside, your program will be more useful if it accepts file names as command-line parameters.  Then you get the benefits of wildcard completion, history, and tab completion from the shell. (Granted, if you are on Windows, the standard shell is kind of useless.)

Comment: @tripleee Could you expand please?

Comment: Having your program interactively prompt for a file name at a time is enormously improductive.  Making it read its command-line arguments makes it easy to write other programs on top of this program, and removing the interactive prompting removes one important bottleneck from automation.

Comment: I don't think Python allows reading, writing, and appending a file all in one go. I suggest you first open the file for reading, save the content you want to write in a variable, the same file for writing, then writing using the variable. EDIT: Reading further, you can. Just use `r+` or `w+` or `a+`

Answer (score 1):

The [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function accepts two parameters (or three, but not relevant here), not a file name and a list of permissions.  You seem to be looking for `"r+"`.

The error message means that `open` tried to use `"r"` as a buffer size (that's the optional third argument) which needs to be an integer, obviously.

The fix is to replace `"r", "a", "w"` with `"r+"` so that the call to `open()` has exactly two arguments.

```
hand = open(name, "r+")
```

(The parentheses you had around `name` were superfluous, so I also took those out.)

Comment: What does this mean? I'm a total beginner

Comment: Reading the documentation, seems like either one of `r+`, `w+`, or `a+` will work by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The 'int' being sought is the integer for **buffering**. You've comma-delimited your 'mode' list, which is not the proper procedure; it reads `"r"` properly as the mode string, but when it reaches `"w"` it tries to take it in as the buffering int and spits back an error.

If you want to read *and* write, use `"w+"`. To append to the end of the file, use `f.seek(0, 2)` before writing. To reset back to the start of the file, use `f.seek(0, 0)`. And make sure to call `f.close()` before you end the program.

References: [`open` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), [`file.seek` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)

Answer (score 0):

For read and write from / to a file I would recommend:

```
with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(output)
    f.truncate()
```

Here's how you read a file, and then write to it (overwriting any existing data), without closing and reopening.

More, for all the options you can do:

```
with open(filename, "ra+") as f:
    ...
```

Comment: That's possible? I'm getting a `ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode`.